# How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript? tell me

Tags: javascript, django

i used this code

```
const copyBtns = [...document.getElementsByClassName('copy')]
  copyBtns.forEach(btn=> btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    content = btn.getAttribute('data-content')
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(content)
    btn.textContent = "تم النسخ"
  }))
```

copy not working on click in mobile, and it's working with any computer.
what is the solution?

Comment: `not working on click in mobile` all mobile? apple only? android only? please be specific - I've read on safari that it may only work in a pointerDown or pointerUp event handler

Comment: you can use https://github.com/sindresorhus/clipboardy and give it a try.

Comment: @KhaledMdTuhidulHossain horrible - you need to install an App before it works in Android ... pass

Comment: Make sure you're using https. Otherwise clipboard may not be availalble.

Answer (score -2):

I've used this approach in the past for web apps, which uses jQuery to construct a hidden `<input>` field and copy the text from there. This seems to work well cross-platform, including Android and iOS devices.

```
const temp = $('<input>');
$('body').append(temp);
temp.val('YOUR STRING HERE').select();
document.execCommand('copy');
temp.remove();
```

I suspect the reason your code is not working is because the mobile browser does not have access to (or support for) `clipboard`. [Can I Use?](https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.clipboard) is a great resource to determine support for CSS/HTML and other browser APIs .

Comment: execCommand is deprecated

Comment: also, don't use jquery in an answer where the question doesn't ask for jquery

Comment: @bravo using jQuery _is_ an answer; the question did not explicitly ask for a non-jQuery solution

Comment: Answering with jquery where it was not tagged in the question is not wrong, but many people consider it irrelevant for modern coding - sure the plain javascript code may be a little longer, but it'll be an order of magnitude more performant